# Is there a way to use local xsd elements in WSDL

Tags: xsd, wsdl

I can't seem to use local xsd element in the WSDL schema, since i can't create an external xsd (project conditions).

```xml
<types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:fs_req="urn:rg:fs_req" xmlns:sf_facto="urn:rg:sf_facto">
        <xsd:import namespace="urn:rg:sf_facto" schemaLocation="ROOT_sf_facto_SF_facto_V00_05.xsd" />
        <xsd:import namespace="urn:rg:fs_req"     schemaLocation="ROOT_fs_req_fs_req_V00_04.xsd" />

        <xsd:element name="getDetailsAction1" type="fs_req:fs_req_fs_req" /
        <xsd:element name="getDetailsAction1Response"      type="sf_facto:SF_facto_SF_facto"/>

    </xsd:schema>
</types>
```

Below the call of the xsd element (Not valide part!)

```xml
<message name="detailMpaResponse">
    <part name="getDetail" element="tns:getDetailsAction1Response" />
</message>
<message name="detailMpaRequest">       
    <part name="getDetailResponse" element="tns:getDetailsAction1" />
</message>
```

How can i have a valide wsdl with the local xsd element?

Comment: Sara - Can you post the full WSDL file. I suspect that there is something in the `<wsdl:definitions>` element at the top of the file that might clue us in to the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

The problem looks to be with your namespace qualifier in the `<part>` nodes.

**EDIT:**

In looking closer at your original post I think the schema element might hold the values we need. Give this code a shot:

```
<message name="detailMpaResponse">
    <part name="getDetail" element="fs_req:getDetailsAction1Response" />
</message>
<message name="detailMpaRequest">       
    <part name="getDetailResponse" element="sf_facto:getDetailsAction1" />
</message>
```

Comment: I modified my code like that `<message name="detailMpaRequest">       
<part name="getDetailResponse" element="getDetailsAction1" />
</message>` but it doesn't seems to work!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say: "it doesn't seem to work". Are you running this through a validator? Are you getting an error message? If so can you post it?

Comment: I tried to validate it with eclipse it gives me an error (The part 'pRechercheInfoRfPat' has an invalid value 'getDetail' defined for its type. Type 
 declarations must refer to valid values defined in a schema.)

Comment: I missed this in your OP but I believe the namespace identifiers you need might be listed in the schema element: `<xsd:schema xmlns:fs_req="urn:rg:fs_req" xmlns:sf_facto="urn:rg:sf_facto">`. See the edit to my original answer...

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a new targetNamespace for the xs:schema in your wsdl:types and add it to wsdl:definitions, something like this:

```
<types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:types="urn:rg:types" targetNameSpace="urn:rg:types" xmlns:fs_req="urn:rg:fs_req" xmlns:sf_facto="urn:rg:sf_facto">
        <xsd:import namespace="urn:rg:sf_facto" schemaLocation="ROOT_sf_facto_SF_facto_V00_05.xsd" />
        <xsd:import namespace="urn:rg:fs_req"     schemaLocation="ROOT_fs_req_fs_req_V00_04.xsd" />

        <xsd:element name="getDetailsAction1" type="fs_req:fs_req_fs_req" />
        <xsd:element name="getDetailsAction1Response" type="sf_facto:SF_facto_SF_facto"/>

    </xsd:schema>
</types>
```

then add the new namespace to wsdl:definitions:

```
xmlns:types="urn:rg:types"
```

and then refer to it in the message parts:

```
<message name="detailMpaResponse">
    <part name="getDetail" element="types:getDetailsAction1Response" />
</message>
<message name="detailMpaRequest">       
    <part name="getDetailResponse" element="types:getDetailsAction1" />
</message>
```

The new namespace can't match the ones you import.

Answer (score 0):

Just did a quick experiment (using Eclipse WSDL editor), and the following code was generated when I selected "using a type" from an external XSD (in the same directory as the WSDL file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/NewWSDLFile/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="NewWSDLFile"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/NewWSDLFile/" xmlns:xsd1="http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema">
    <wsdl:types>
        (...)
        <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xsd:import namespace="http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema"
                schemaLocation="NewXMLSchema.xsd">
            </xsd:import>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="NewOperationRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" type="xsd1:externalSchemaParamType" />
    </wsdl:message>
    (...)
```

In your case: is "tns" the name space of the externa XSD?

Comment: "element" is a valid attribute of the `<message>` node. That isn't the problem.

Comment: @pmartin you are right, you can use the "element" in the message part.  This leaves the "name space" declaration of the XSD in the <wsdl:defenitions> as the possible problem.

Comment: @emgsilva The problem is can't use external xsd, have to create new elements in the wsdl.

Comment: I understand. I suggest you publish the <wsdl:definitions> of your WSDL file and also the XSD files you are referring to in order to help you further with your problem.